# Prefix column names in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

with every project, I automatically run into a problem with reserved SQL word when I use properties like `status` or `user` in my Grails domain classes.

So I always have to add a

```
static mapping = {
    status column:'prefix_status'
}
```

to my classes.

I now wonder if there is an easy way to prefix all columns with a given string?

If there is nothing out of the box, I guess it would be possible to create a plugin which automagically injects such a mapping in all domain classes - can someone point me to a code example which modifies a class whenever it changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already answered in the manual:

[Object Relational Mapping (GORM) - Custom Naming Strategy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customNamingStrategy)

Add to `DataSource.groovy` Config:

```
hibernate {
    ...
    naming_strategy = com.myco.myproj.CustomNamingStrategy
}
```

Custom Naming Class (under `src/groovy/com/myco/myproj/CustomNamingStrategy.groovy`):

```
package com.myco.myproj

import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
import org.hibernate.util.StringHelper

class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
        "prefix_" + StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx! The documentation quality is really great and I should re-read it more often :-)